# Redirecting multiple requests in one controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Good time of day. It is necessary to redirect several requests to a single controller. For example, the requests "/abc_1" and "/abc_2" are redirected to the controller "abc".Using Route for the controller method does not help:

```cs
[Route("abc_1")]
[Route("abc_2")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Json("OK");
}
```

Perhaps you need to use Map Route in Global.asax? If so, how do I specify a pattern for incoming urls?

UPD: Yes, it looks silly enough, but there is a business requirement, because of which the processing of urls is almost identical. Therefore, I would not like to create 2 almost identical controllers.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved using routing in Global.asax (the RegisterRoutes method):

```cs
routes.MapRoute(<name>, "{abc_*}", new { controller = <controller _name>, action = "Index" });
```